# How do I make it so that when I check one radio button, the other radio button in the same form get unchecked in React?

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button, radio-group

In the form below, when I click the first radio button then I click the second radio button, both remain checked. The behaviour I want is for when I click on radio button, the other radio button gets unchecked automatically. I am using React.js with styled components.

```html
<form>
<input type="radio"/>
<input type="radio"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the same name to all the radio buttons (but different values).

```html
<form>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="1"/> 1st
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="2"/> 2nd
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have give each radio button a name property with the same value like "group1". Like so:

```html
<form>
<input type="radio" name="group1"/>
<input type="radio" name="group1"/>
</form>
```